# Flutter code, accept value from user display required field

Tags: dart, flutter

**Hello, I am developing an app in which the user should enter the integer values.according to that values we should display those number of text fields..

- for Example:

  ```
            1) enter total number of subject=10;
            2) click on the button;
            3) After button is clicked should display 10 text fields;
            4) I have no idea what to do so if you know then help me plz.**
  ```

  import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

  ```
  class imcaaddsubject extends StatefulWidget {
    @override
    _imcaaddsubjectState createState() => _imcaaddsubjectState();
  }

  class _imcaaddsubjectState extends State<imcaaddsubject> {
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
        child: Card(
          child: ListView(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
            children: <Widget>[
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
              ),
              new TextField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide: BorderSide(style: BorderStyle.solid)),
                  labelText: "NUMBER OF SUBJECTS",
                  hintText: "Enter number of subjects",
                ),keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15),
              ),
              new RaisedButton(
                child: Text(
                  "OK",
                  style:
                      TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                ),
                color: Colors.cyan,
                onPressed: () {},
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      );
    }
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(
      home: MyApp(),
    ));

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  MyAppState createState() => MyAppState();
}

class MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  int numberOfSubjects = 0;

  Widget subjectsBuilder(int numberOfSubjects) {
    if (numberOfSubjects > 0) {
      return ListView.builder(
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, numberOfSubjects) {
          return TextField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: "enter a text"),
          );
        },
        itemCount: numberOfSubjects,
      );
    } else {
      return SizedBox();
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(children: <Widget>[
        Expanded(
          child: Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
            child: Card(
              child: ListView(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                children: <Widget>[
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
                  ),
                  new TextField(
                    onSubmitted: (String value) {
                      setState(() {
                        numberOfSubjects = int.parse(value);
                      });
                    },
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderSide: BorderSide(style: BorderStyle.solid)),
                      labelText: "NUMBER OF SUBJECTS",
                      hintText: "Enter number of subjects",
                    ),
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: subjectsBuilder(numberOfSubjects),
        )
      ]),
    );
  }
}
```

this code will display a number of text fields according to user input below the first text field , of course you can render it in a new page .. also you don't have to use a button , it's enough to user submit text .

Comment: There is no button. on press, the button should display the text field

Comment: if you want to add button you can , but no need for it once user enter the number and click submit ( or done or correct mark ) on the **keyboard** , text fields will be shown .

Comment: if you think this answer is useful please mark it as correct or vote it up .